# Qt - Relative path issue

Tags: c++, qt

1. I created a new file (data.xml) in my solution explorer in Qt Creator, which automatically was added to the `Other` files folder.
2. I created a piece of code that reads data from that file but there was a problem: the file could not be found.
3. I copied the file to `c://data.xml` and changed the path in the code also to `c://data.xml` and everything worked well.

My question is: how to handle these relative paths?

This is the code:

```
    QString filename="data.xml";
    QVector<Student> students;
    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        return;
    }
    QDomDocument doc;
    if (!doc.setContent(&file))
    {
        file.close();
        return;;
    }
    file.close();
    QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
    QDomElement studentNode = root.firstChildElement("Student");
    while(!studentNode.isNull())
    {
        QString firstName=studentNode.firstChildElement("FirstName").text();
        QString lastName=studentNode.firstChildElement("LastName").text();
        int age=studentNode.firstChildElement("Age").text().toInt();
        students.push_back(Student(firstName, lastName, age));
        studentNode=studentNode.nextSiblingElement("Student");
    }
```

This is the project file:

```
QT       += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = GUI1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    editdialog.cpp \
    student.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    editdialog.h \
    student.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    editdialog.ui

OTHER_FILES += \
    data.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All such paths are calculated relative to the directory from where you launch your application. QtCreator launches programs from their own directories. In your case I would recommend you to add this line to you `pro` file:

```
DESTDIR = $$PWD
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Is this the one and only solution for using relative paths in Qt?

Comment: Well, `QString QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath ()` contains absolute path to your app directory, so you can always do something like this: `QString fileName = QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath()).absoluteFilePath("../etc/data.xml")`. Anyway, you need to know exactly where your program is located. I recommend using standard Unix directories, like "bin", "etc", "share" and so on.